# How to poll webapi request in the background without interrupting user experience?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

At the moment I have an app which allows user to send data to a restful webapi, whilst connected to the internet, but this app should also work offline. Thus I am storing user actions in a SQLlite database. This information should be persisted to the webapi when the mobile device finds internet connection.
I have implemented

```
public bool IsConnected(){

        var connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService (ConnectivityService);
        var activeConnection = connectivityManager.ActiveNetworkInfo;

        if ((activeConnection != null) && activeConnection.IsConnected) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
}
```

This is called by the OnCreateOptionMenu() of every activity. Which works fine. However when I place a webapi request, which is sadly synchronous call causes the app to display a blank screen until it has processed this. Now this is the user experience I would like to replace with, something similar like ASYNC (asynchronus) request, which works everything in the background without any interruption. But I am struggling to implement this. I did have a Sync button on the app home screen, which onclick ran async call however I do not trust the app users to press this button. Hence I would like to trigger this work in the background. Can someone please advise?

Comment: Why you dont manually run the asynchronous code instead of wanting users to do that?
Also parse.com is a great way to deal with online databases and asynchronous calls. i think it will help you a lot if you are ok on using parse

Comment: So you reckon if i create a void Async method and call that manually when internet connection is found this should work? Sorry I haven't worked with c# Async before so just trying to get my head around it. As I have always seen usages through button event handlers.

Comment: How about using `Task.Run(async () => await YourAsyncMethod())`?

Comment: @MilenPavlov That is something I didnt think of! Thank you, this should help as I can create a new thread to run an async delegate, which WILL run in the background :). I'll give this a try. Thanks again.

Comment: Just make sure you're implementing some sort of locking mechanism to deal with concurrency (if required)..

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbhbke0y(v=vs.110).aspx and this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: if you want to run the async method when internet connection is up you can create a timer to periodically check the internet connection

Comment: @CDrosos how to best implement a timer? I was thinking something like:
When the app is started I use System.Threading.Timer _timer = new Timer(callback, null, duetime, period). But the bit I feel confused about is: as its a phone app, people close app and continue the day after or weekend after, the timer will run for infinity. What would be the best way to implement this? Also when they start the app again, how can I check the timer isnt already on? Do i stop timer (how do i stop timer?) when a user logs out?

Comment: I think in your case i will run the timer in the background https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_1_introduction_to_backgrounding_in_android/ and i would let android to kill the App and the timer. You can also make sure that the timer will be killed on the OnDestroy event, you can manually kill it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @MilenPavlov and @CDrosos.

I went with CDrosos's solution as this was ideally what I was looking for.

I created a static timer member in BaseActivity, which on app start is set. This way no concurrencies will occur. This allowed me to create a timer elapsed method which would check database for pending web requests, and post if IsConnected and pendingWebRequests.Any().

```
    if (_timer == null)
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Interval = (1000 * 60) * 5; // 5 ;
        _timer.Start();
    }
```

Then make webapi request.